# React-Native passing style to props.children

Tags: react-native, react-props

I am trying to pass style to children, my code is :

```
render() {
    const RotateData = this.RotateValueHolder.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    });

    Object.assign(this.props.children.props.style,{'transform': [{'rotate': RotateData}] });

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            {this.props.children}
        </View>
    );
}
```

I getting this error :

```
Invariant Violation: Transform with key of "rotate" must be a string:
{"rotate":"0deg"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate can be only used by the animated component, so you need to apply the style to Animated.View or any Animated element. so try to use it with animated component.